# USEARCH clustering

Tags: bioinformatics

I have some problems when using usearch for protein clustering.

When I use the USEARCH command line alone:

`usearch11.0.667_i86linux32 -cluster_fast ./my_fasta.proteins.faa -id 0.9 -clusters ./protein.id09.clusters`

I will get the clustering results of 4 protein clusters.

But when I put about 10k usearch command lines into a bash files (about 10k+ protein faa files need to clustering), and use:

`bash usearch.id09.sh`

The same protein clustering result will decrease to 2 protein clusters.

The usearch version is usearch11.0.667_i86 32-bit, CentOS7.

Comment: So `-clusters ./protein.id09.clusters` is your output, correct? Please confirm that this output file only occurs once in your bash script. You may be accidentally overwriting the file.

Comment: Yes, this output file only occurs once in my .sh script.